# Not sure where to put my test in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, testing

I am fairly new to CakePHP and I have a basic blogging application (a mock of twitter), with model Tweet and controller TweetsController. I need to do a unit test to make sure that posts do not exceed 140 characters, so the action I'm testing is the add action in the controller. My question is, where do I do this test, in TweetTest or TweetsControllerTest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You  can read the testing [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#testing-controllers) on cakephp. Since this is a test of a controller action you should do it in TweetsControllerTest. However if you are using a Model validation you can also add it to TweetsTest.

I would prefer both since it would give you more clarity on what goes wrong if the test fails since controller actions are more complex than model validations. It is easier to figure out what is wrong from a failed validation test rather than a failed controller action test. However it is better to both the controller action and the model validation since that allows less assumptions about how the controller action code is written.